# Pass data from functional component to a class component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I try to pass two location coordinates from a functional component to a class component. This is the way that I try to pass data to the class component.

```
function ViewPost() {

    console.log(posts);

    const long = posts?.location?.longitude;
    console.log(long);
    const lat=posts?.location?.latitude;
    console.log(lat);

    const location=[lat,long];

    return(
         <SimpleMap loc={location}/>
    );
}

export default ViewPost;
```

In the class component,

```
const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;

class SimpleMap extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        center: {
            lat: 59.95,
            lng: 30.33
        },
        zoom: 11
    };

    render() {
        const {lat, long}=this.props.loc;
        console.log(lat);
        console.log(long);
        return (
                    <div className="location-box-b" style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
                        <GoogleMapReact
                            bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "" }}
                            defaultCenter={this.props.center}
                            defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
                        >
                            <AnyReactComponent
                                lat={this.props.loc.lat}
                                lng={this.props.loc.long}
                                text="Seller's Location"
                            />
                        </GoogleMapReact>
                    </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SimpleMap;
```

This is the code that I try to get data from the functional component. When I try to do like this

```
const {lat, long}=this.props.loc;
console.log(lat);
console.log(long);
```

print 'undefined' in the console. How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your this.props.loc is an array, this is how you defined it here

```
const location=[lat,long];
```

but you are trying to get properties from it like from object

```
const {lat, long}=this.props.loc;
```

so you have to change it to be an object:

```
const location={lat,long};
```